# Button with link anchor to a div section on the page - no refresh

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a "Make an Enquiry" button which I want when clicked to take the user at a specific section of the same page in which the user can fill in the enquiry form.

For accomplishing this I created this btton:

```
<%= button_to 'Make an Enquiry', user_path(user, anchor: :enquirySection), :method => :get, class: "btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" %>
```

and then set the enquiry section like this:

```
  <div id="enquirySection">
    <%= render "enquiries/form", enquiry: @enquiry %>
  </div>
```

The result of this button was to refresh the page and "scroll" it to the enquriySection. However I don't like the idea of the page being refreshed. Is there a way to avoid this refresh? Should I go with another approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an HTML anchor with a link:

```
<%= link_to "Make an Enquiry", "#enquirySection" %>
```

Rails just renders standard HTML code, so if you want to just scroll to a specific part of the page, you can use the same techniques that work on all browsers, which is to use an identifier (typically `id`), and then let the browser scroll to it

If you wanted to style a button, you'd then be best using CSS. The `button_to` helper creates a form, which won't work for this purpose